# How to wire in an alternate light controller?

Tags: wiring

My townhouse complex has external lights on timed controller.  The controller only supports a single on and off time which means we need to keep adjusting the lights through out the year to avoid wasting power.  [I have implemented an alternate controller that factors in sunrise and sunset times using a micro controller (GHI Fez Panda running .NET Microframework) and a relay](https://github.com/JFarlette/LightController).  I would like to wire it in so that it is possible to switch between the two controllers in case my controller dies or I want to pull it out to update the software etc.

I think I understand how to wire it in but just want to confirm with someone.  Can someone review the following two diagrams and tell me if my changes are correct?  Specifically I am not sure I am handling the common lines correctly.

[image: Existing controller]

[image: New Controller]

Edit:  Thanks for the feedback.  Yes, new controller has external power supply.  With a DPDT for both the hot in and out it would look like the following.

[image]

DPDT 120v 30a switches (which is what the existing controller is rated for) are hard to find and expensive.  [Here is one option I guess.](http://www.westwayelectricsupply.com/3025brn-switch-tog-dp-dt-30a-120-277v-br.html)  If anyone knows of a cheaper option please suggest it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wiring you show will work.

However, connecting the outputs like that means even when the controller is switched off, its output might be hot.  Depending on how it is connected and enclosed, that may or may not be dangerous.

It might be better to use a double pole double throw switch wired so the input and output hots get switch between controllers and the other controller is completely disconnected.

And of course you have to make sure the switch is suitably rated for the max current and voltage of the circuit.

The neutrals should all be connected like you show.  Presumably your controller uses a separate power source since it doesn't have a neutral connection.